# How to use webfont with more than 9 font-weights?

Tags: css, webfonts

I'm trying to use [font with 10 weights](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/font-fabric/muller/).
I want to use it as single font-family.
The problem is i can define only 9 (100,200,300....900).
Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Really...10 weights...I can't think of a usecase where 9 wouldn't get the job done

Comment: Can you try adding the weight name to the font family? Check the font files themselves for names like "Muller Hairline" and use those exactly.

Comment: @MrLister yes, i know. But as i said, i want to use single font-family for all of them.

Comment: @Paulie_D its not about specific usecase. its more "theoretical" question. Is it possible or not?

Comment: @olegmil In that case, the answer is no. CSS weights are keywords, not integer numbers, so you can't specify values in between, say, 300 and 400. Those values simply don't exist for CSS.